# Foreach loop over numbered folders only in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a `ForEach` loop over some folders in order to retrieve their contents and send them to a `Data Flow Task`.

Some of these folders have alphanumeric names (e.g.: `Archive`, `Corrupted`, etc.), while some have numeric names (`05`, `06`, etc.)

How can I only loop over the numeric folder names, and ignore the others?

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you using?  2008 or 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all the folders, and then inside your loop, start with a script task that checks the name of folder and continues if the name is numeric, or does nothing if it is not.